# Apache reverse proxy backend authentication

Tags: apache, ldap, mod-proxy

I've setup apache reverse proxy for my application with ldap authentication.
The problem is that the backend application also requires authentication.
After I entered ldap credentials, it always returns 401 and doesn't prompt for the application authentication.
The backend uses different credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the backend-server uses the very same LDAP authentication as the frontend you might want to have a look env var `proxy-chain-auth` in [docs for mod_proxy_http](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_http.html#env).

Comment: No. The backend uses different credentials

Comment: Is it a static backend credential? You should provide such details in your question.

Comment: Yes, I did mention that in the question. And yes, it is static credentials